# Simple Bayesian meta-analysis in R

Tags: r, bayesian, meta-analysis

Is there a simple way to conduct a Bayesian meta-analysis in R in order to support equivalence between the effects of two study types? E.g., Bayes factors would be perfect.

So, for example I have this meta-data:

```
met_stat = structure(
    list(
        cohens_d = c(
            0.667736711989537,
            0.793600760953399,
            1.3124515035473,
            1.30412598975747,
            0.958640726783857,
            0.930081791487542,
            0.901946855478192,
            1.02166264217578
        ),
        variance_d = c(
            0.0193529475194948,
            0.0375704337470874,
            0.0229130218784657,
            0.052279224149358,
            0.0115091851365868,
            0.0219378537485526,
            0.00984899858515591,
            0.0209744864843904
        ),
        version = c(
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i",
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i",
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i",
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i"
        ),
        study = c(
            "Verschuere, Kleinberg, & Theocharidou (2015) single",
            "Verschuere, Kleinberg, & Theocharidou (2015) single",
            "Verschuere, Kleinberg, & Theocharidou (2015) multiple",
            "Verschuere, Kleinberg, & Theocharidou (2015) multiple",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 1",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 1",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 2",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 2"
        )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -8L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

And I want to know the effect of "version".
With the frequentist approach, I could super easily get a meta-analysis done e.g. with the metafor package, in a single function:

```
REML <-
    rma(
        cohens_d,
        variance_d,
        data = met_stat,
        method = "REML",
        mods = ~ version
    )
```

Then `REML` has all the info I need (and I can nicely print it with `forest()`).

Is there any kind of **simple** Bayesian analogue? I don't want to have to read loads of technical papers to get this done - I'll probably never even need it in the future.

---

Now, I found this `metaBMA` package that at least seems to imply that I can get simple Bayes factors for a moderator in a meta-analysis. (Most other Bayesian don't seem to allow moderators.) But there is, naturally, no sensible description whatsoever on how exactly to use it and/or how to interpret the output.

Below is what I managed so far.

Firstly, I now calculated SEs because that's needed apparently (instead of variance), so here is how my new dataset looks like:

```
met_bf = structure(
    list(
        cohens_d = c(
            0.958640726783857,
            0.930081791487542,
            0.901946855478192,
            1.02166264217578,
            1.07356225952092,
            1.44689069627541,
            0.723488965731349,
            0.839350257451386
        ),
        sed = c(
            0.107492799152646,
            0.148930067394091,
            0.0994437724487224,
            0.145065264316275,
            0.0805875458638765,
            0.141971247410652,
            0.0730295485698532,
            0.158223382018453
        ),
        study = c(
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 1",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 1",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 2",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2015) Study 2",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2016) Study 1",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2016) Study 1",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2016) Study 2",
            "Kleinberg & Verschuere (2016) Study 2"
        ),
        version = c(
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i",
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i",
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i",
            "simulated",
            "p_vs_i"
        )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, -8L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
              "data.frame")
)
```

Then I did this:

```
bayes_model = metaBMA::meta_random(
    y = cohens_d~version,
    SE = sed,
    labels = study,
    data = met_bf
)
```

And this indeed contains some results, but nothing that resembles Bayes factors or something that proves equivalence.

There is the `metaBMA::inclusion()` function for inclusion Bayes factors, but I don't know how I could integrate it; it requires at least two models. I was thinking of excluding and including 'version', and then comparing the two obtained models, but I'm not sure whether it makes sense the way I do it - and even if it does, I do not understand the output.

Anyway, here is how it would look:

```
bayes_model1 = metaBMA::meta_random(
    y = cohens_d,
    SE = sed,
    labels = study,
    data = met_bf
)
bayes_model2 = metaBMA::meta_random(
    y = cohens_d~version,
    SE = sed,
    labels = study,
    data = met_bf
)
metaBMA::inclusion(logml = list(bayes_model1, bayes_model2))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the CRAN Task View https://cran.r-project.org/view=MetaAnalysis which has a number of Bayesian packages? Questions about M-A in R might be better directed to the mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//

Comment: I haven't, thanks for the link, looks very useful! Still, I hope someone might give a more direct solution here. Otherwise I'll try to dig deeper and give an answer myself.